# Why Android Studio converts some primitive Kotlin types as conditional/safe operator?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

I know I shouldn't ask "why" questions in here, but I hope this is one of the allowed exceptions since it is a code related question. I just don't know the consequences yet on this new language.

I'm using Android studio 3.0 canary 3, and I'm converting java code to Kotlin. A lot of the code is being converted manually, but some other code I'm converting it by copy/pasting java to a new Kotlin file.

So far, so good. However, I started to notice this:

Java code:

```
class MyClass {
    private String userId;
    private Long newFolderId;
    private int oldFolderId;

    public MyClass(final String userId, final Long newFolderId, final int oldFolderId) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.newFolderId = newFolderId;
        this.oldFolderId = oldFolderId;
    }
}
```

I copy this small chunk of code to Kotlin, and it gets automatically converted to this:

```
class MyClass(private val userId: String, 
              private val newFolderId: Long?, 
              private val oldFolderId: Int)
```

So, my question at this point is why did the `Long` get converted to `Long?`

If this is able null safety, shouldn't ALL of the variables then be `?`? Like, `String?` and `Int?`

Why just `Long`?

Also, I know I'm passing a long for this class, so would it be bad to just remove the `?` from the Long, and just call it `Long`?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Long is not primitive type. long is primitive.

Comment: So `Long` is not a type in kotlin, but `Int` is? How do you get the primitive of `Int`?

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Kotlin makes no distinction between primitives and boxed types.

Comment: ok, but that still doesnt make any sense. what's so special about `Long` that makes it a primitive, yet every other structure is a type? (like Double, Int..)

Comment: "I know I shouldn't ask "why" questions in here" What gave you that odd idea? There's millions of questions like that.

Comment: :) true, but there are many "why does my code not work" without any information

Comment: I can see why `Long` -> `Long?`, since in Java, you can also pass `null` for the second parameter. But I don't understand why it doesn't make it `String?`, since you can also pass `null` for the first parameter. `int` -> `Int` makes sense, because an `int` can not be `null`.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar String isn't primitive either.

Comment: @Thomas I am talking about Java. `Long` is not primitive in Java and can be null, on the other hand `long` is primitive and will always have some value. `String`  probably has special treatment due its nature - empty string can be used as default value. In many languages Strings have special treatment and considerations. Most of the time you would prefer `String` not to be nullable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question is why Kotlin converts primitive Kotlin types as nullable types?

First - Kotlin does not have primitive types - it only optimizes some basic types representation on the JVM when it can. [Kotlin Basic Types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html)

Second - here it is important to note that you are converting Java code to Kotlin. So your Java code and its types are the ones that make difference in conversion.

In Java `Long` is class, and not primitive type. In Java `long` is primitive counterpart to `Long`.

So your `Long` parameter can be null in Java and it was rightfully converted to nullable `Long?` Your `int` parameter is primitive type in Java - it cannot be null - and it is converted as non-nullable `Int`

If you had different Java class declaration

```
class MyClass {
    private String userId;
    private long newFolderId;
    private int oldFolderId;

    public MyClass(final String userId, final long newFolderId, final int oldFolderId) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.newFolderId = newFolderId;
        this.oldFolderId = oldFolderId;
    }
}
```

it would be converted as

```
internal inner class MyClass(private val userId: String, private val newFolderId: Long, private val oldFolderId: Int)
```

As you can see primitive `long` is converted to non-nullable `Long`

---

Why exactly is non-primitive `String` type converted as non-nullable?

That part of the question is somewhat opinion-based - or at least answer is.

`String` probably has special treatment due its nature - empty string can be used as default value. In many languages strings have special treatment and considerations. Most of the time you would prefer `String` variable not to be nullable. Since Kotlin emphasizes null safety it is logical that default code conversion will treat `String` as non-nullable.

---

As far as null-safety is concerned. Every piece of code when you can use non-nullable type is safer and simpler to deal with than code that uses nullable type. So `Long` is preferred to `Long?` where applicable.

Comment: that's an awesome answer and explanation. thank you!